# How do I use RSA-SHA512 as signing algorithm in defaultAlgorithmSuite in custom bindings?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am signing XML as per :
Signature Algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512 Digest Algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512 Canonicalization Algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#

But I have failed to find support for SHA512 in WCF. Is there a workaround to this?

Below is my code:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="McBinding">
         <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" includeTimestamp="false" defaultAlgorithmSuite="??"
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
        </security>
        <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues I had was with no support of RSA-SHA512 signature algorithm. It can be achieved by using Custom Signature Algorithm. Then add it to Default Signature Algorithm in your custom binding.

```
 public class MyCustomAlgorithmSuite : SecurityAlgorithmSuite { }
```

Also create Signature for this as:

```
public class RsaPkCs1Sha512SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{}
```

Then add it to :

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha512SignatureDescription),
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512");
```

However we ran into an issue with signing BinarySecurity Token. It can be signed by adding:

```
assymetricKey.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());
```

However this creates a new signed Binary Security Token and you will end up with two BST. The solution to this is by :

```
            assymetricKey.InitiatorTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never};
        assymetricKey.RecipientTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never};
```

This messes up with your SignedInfo to lose reference to BST and we are stuck.

Anyway we ended up not using WCF capability and instead used:

```
SignedXML class.
```

For reference to how to use it here is the link: 
https://gist.github.com/luizvaz/43ccbd85b16b6802218b50b6d34c26de

Also, thing to note here is if you are implementing signature algorithm RSA-SHA512 from certificate then you will need to use extension method (make sure to use .net 4.6.2 or higher). For old versions:

[SignedXml Compute Signature with SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005876/signedxml-compute-signature-with-sha256)

```
signedXml.SigningKey = RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(cert);
```

Also, if you are adding prefix to the Signature as `ds` then you will need to remove references from `SignedInfo`, re-compute signature and add it back.

[Generate Digital Signature but with a Specific Namespace Prefix ("ds:")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579938/generate-digital-signature-but-with-a-specific-namespace-prefix-ds)

I hope this helps to having similar issues.

Comment: Marvelous reply. Thanks so much.