# Creating custom MessageHeader with namespace in WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I need to build the following Receipts XML structure including the xmlns:u namespace and add it to the SOAP header. So the end outgoing SOAP header should look something like this:

```
    <Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
     <s:Header>
       <u:Receipts xmlns:u="http://MyCompany/abc">
        <Receipt>
         <Id />
         <Text />
        </Receipt>
       <Receipt>
        <Id />
        <Text />
       </Receipt>
       <Receipt>
        <Id />
        <Text />
       </Receipt>
    </u:Receipts>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body />
</Envelope>
```

I'm overriding the MessageHeader class and build the xml in OnWriteHeaderContents method. However, I can’t get the correct xml/namespace. Code sample is appreciated!

Comment: could you post your code? anyway, to change namespace you need to create a new Message object. Did you set the namespace in your contract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is our solution at the moment, which works fine.

```
    public class ReceiptsHeader : MessageHeader
{
    private const string HeaderName = "Receipts";
    private const string HeaderNamespace = "http://MyCompany/abc";

    public override string Name => HeaderName;

    public override string Namespace => HeaderNamespace;

    private readonly XmlDocument _usageReceipt = new XmlDocument();

    public ReceiptsHeader(IEnumerable elements)
    {
        var headerString = new StringBuilder("<Receipts xmlns=\"http://MyCompany/abc\">");
        foreach (var elem in elements)
        {
            // Build <Receipt> nodes here...
        }
        headerString.Append("</Receipts>");

        _usageReceipt.LoadXml(headerString.ToString());
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in _usageReceipt.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes)
            writer.WriteNode(node.CreateNavigator(), false);

    }
}
```

We're then adding this to the SOAP header in the BeforeSendReply method, something like this:

```
ReceiptsHeader head = new ReceiptsHeader(elements);
reply.Headers.Add(head);
```